# Automatic calculation of column value and retaining the selected item in DDL on addition of new row to GridView

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an AJAX tab container, inside which on PersonDays tab I have two problems:

**1:**
As you can view from the below given image that the item value selected in the DDL for ResourceType is getting changed to the default/ 1st value of the DDL while the new row is being created after clicking on "Add" button.
(The DDL's items are not being fetched from a DB table).
How to fix the value on the item selected by the user before clicking on the "Add" button?

**2:**
How the value in the "TotalCost" column can be calculated automatically on the change of focus from "CostPerDay", that is "No.ofDaysXCostPerDay" ***without clicking on the "Add"*** button and simultaneously filled up in the textBox present below the GridView and in the textBox present on the "EstimatedCost" tab before addition of the new row?
(In my Current state of form it gets calculated/ filled only after I click on the "Add" button")

["You Can Find the screen shot along with Solution File and DB script HERE"](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=AD2546A1BBF7A705!106)